# собственный класс-исключение java

Tags: java, исключения, конструктор

Пытаюсь реализовать собственный класс-исключение.
Согласно условию он должен выводить сообщение об ошибке по умолчанию ("Устройство недоступно") и иметь поле "устройство" с геттером, которое хранит невалидный объект-устройство, который привел к появлению исключения.

Делаю так:

```
public class DeviceValidationException extends RuntimeException {
public void start() throws IllegalStateException{
    throw new IllegalStateException ("Device is not valid for operation");
}
protected int device;

public int getDevice() throws IllegalStateException{
    try {
        return device;
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e){
        System.out.println("Device is not valid for operation");
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Но есть серьезное подозрение, что это неправильно и мой гет-метод совершенно не хранит то, что нужно. Кроме того нужен ли мне сеттер в пару?

Далее необходимо реализовать конструктор с 2 аргументами-строкой, которой будет передаваться имя операции, для которой устройство оказалось невалидным (я так понимаю, что это будет метод getDevice но как это сделать,увы, не понимаю) и объектом-устройством (device Device), который привёл к появлению исключения. При этом конструктор должен вызвать родительский конструктор с аргументом-строкой, но передать не входящую строку, а собрать её из сообщения по умолчанию и, если входящая не null, добавить ее через пробел. Аргумент device задаёт значение полю device. И тут проблема возникла еще на объявлении конструктора(

```
    DeviceValidationException (String operation, Device device){
    super(operation, device);
}
```

Компилятор ругается на device.

Comment: А есть у вас класс Device? Или это только поле int. Ведь сюда DeviceValidationException (String operation, Device device) вы хотите передать объект класса Device.

Comment: Есть класс,который имплементит интерфейс Device.

Comment: сеттер - не нужен, если вы не хотите изменять экземпляр

Answer (score 3):

У вас код исключения, код который бросает исключение и код который обрабатывает исключение почему-то смешаны в кучу.

Класс исключения:

```
public class DeviceValidationException extends RuntimeException {
    private Device device;

    public DeviceValidationException (Device device) {
         super("Device " + device.getName() + " is not valid for operation");
         this.device = device;
    }

    public Device getDevice() {
       return device;
    }
```

Пример обработки:

```
    try {
        //код который бросает исключение
    }
    catch (DeviceValidationException e) {
        System.out.println(e.message());
        //можно сделать что-нибудь с device
        e.getDevice().doAnything()
    }
}
```

Comment: Только начинаю свой путь в этом деле, вот и путаюсь. Спасибо за помощь))